# Laravel 4: many to many (insertion)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have these tables in DB:

```
[posts, cats (categories), posts_cats (pivote)]
```

the relation between posts table and cats is many to many

I declared the relation in the models classes:

```
//Post.php
public function cats()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('cats');
}



//Cats.php
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('posts');
}
```

the question is, How to insert new post with multiple categories?

thanks,

Comment: Your pivot table should be called: post_cat (singular vs plural). You could use an alternative pivot table name, but then you need to provide that table's name as the second argument to the belongsToMany()-method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's say you know the id of the post then you can attach a single cat like this:

```
Post::find($post_id)->cats()->attach($cat_id);
```

Or attach multiple cats like this:

```
$cat_ids = array(1,2,3,4);
Post::find($post_id)->cats()->attach($cat_ids);
```

If you got the Post model object in a variable, lets say $post:

```
$post->cats()->attach($cat_id);

// Or with multiple
$cat_ids = array(1,2,3,4);
$post->cats()->attach($cat_ids);
```

If you have a single category as an model object in, lets say $model:

```
$post->cats()->save($model);
```

Watch out with [@Gadoma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23908569/662581). Its not wrong, but if you want to add categories to an post that already has categories then you should use attach() instead of sync(). Sync() will delete all others that are not provided to it when used.

edit:
So if you are creating a new Post then you probably are doing something like this:

```
$post = new Post;
$post->title = 'The title';
$post->something_else = 'Lorem';
$post->save();

//So now you have both the model object (the $post variable) and the id ($post->id).

$post->cats()->attach($cat_ids);
```

Comment: what if I don't know post id ( adding new post with its catergories )

Answer (score 1):

When you insert the post, then itterate over the categories and attach them to the new post. Something like that:

```
// $categories is an array of the categories to attach
foreach ($category_id in $categories) {
    // Get a category object 
    $category = CategoryModel::find($category_id);
    // $post is the new post 
    $post->cats()->attach($category);
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models

> **Inserting Related Models (Many To Many)**
>
> [...]
>   You may also use the sync method to attach related models. The sync
>   method accepts an array of IDs to place on the pivot table. After this
>   operation is complete, only the IDs in the array will be on the
>   intermediate table for the model:

And a code example:

```
$post = new Post(array('field1'=>'value1','fieldN'=>'valueN')) //example create new post
$categoryIds = array(1,3,4,5); //ids of (cats) categories you want the post to go into
$post->cats()->sync($categoryIds); //synchronise pivot table content with $categoryIds
```

Comment: display error: "MassAssignmentException
title" refer to $post = new Post(array('title' => Input::get('title'), 'topic'=>Input::get('topic')));

Comment: This, so much of this!

5.1 docs link:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#syncing-for-convenience